# XCode 4, intellisense with C files

Tags: c, xcode4, box2d

I have an Objective-C project and I imported some c libraries such as box2d.
When I write out "b2V". the menu pops up for b2Vector.
But if I declare variables of C types, it doesn't auto complete when I try to use them.
Nor if I do "body->..."

Is it possible to make this work in XCode 4

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.
Basically, open up Utilities, then go to localization, add English.

Comment: Actually, I didn't solve it, I still get undesired side effects